# How can I monitor if my production ASP.NET application is resetting on its own?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis-6, performance

Can I objectively determine if my production ASP.NET web application is resetting its application pool? It could be for whatever reason (for example, an error occurred or memory topped off). I don't have direct access to my production servers, so when I want something on the server, I have ask specifically for it like PerfMon counters to run. It is a running IIS 6.0.

I understand that I could use PerfMon to catch ASP.NET Application Restarts. If I was not monitoring that PerfMon, is there anything that can tell me the application restarted sometime in the past?

Comment: Maybe this will happen when The IIS application pool is shut down after 30 minutes of inactivity.
So I've resolved this issue with simply code-behind, you can check here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339997/how-to-always-your-warm-up-asp-net-websites-webform-mvc?noredirect=1#comment43136405_27339997](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339997/how-to-always-your-warm-up-asp-net-websites-webform-mvc) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need access to the Event Logs.

Depending on your IIS version you might have to enable the worker processing recycling events.

For IIS 6: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756146(WS.10).aspx

For IIS 7: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling

For more info, ask again on serverfault.com

Comment: Do you know if I can use adsutil.vbs to identify the current status of those metabase properties?

Comment: @MadCookie: sorry, no idea.  Although I'm sure a simple look through the event logs will tell you whether they are enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

If all you really care about is if the application resets, you can just add some sort of Email alert, or logging, in the Application_Start of your global.asax.

This would tell you when, and how often, the application starts up, but wouldn't give you any details as to why it happened.

This would at least give you the information you needed to look at specific times for when your application is resetting.